# Connection between Gauss and Poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I know that these distributions are connected by the central limit theorem.

But as it is written [here](http://users.physics.harvard.edu/%7Eschwartz/181Files/1-Probability.pdf): The central limit theorem says that the distribution of the mean of N draws from a probability distribution approaches a Gaussian of width $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$ for large N.

In the same script, in Eq(70) he says the standard deviation of a poisson distribution is $\sigma = \sqrt{\lambda t}$

Below Eq(79) he says the standard deviation of the gaussian (as limit of the poisson) is also  $\sigma = \sqrt{\lambda t}$.

For me this is confusing, where is with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ ?

In our case, the central limit theorem says that the distribution of the mean of N draws from the poisson distribution approaches a Gaussian.

As in the example of the radioactive decay:

I measure N times, the number of decays during the time t (this is the mean) and consider the distribution. This should be a Gaussian? But in this script, he do not sample over anything, he just says that he consider m >> 1 with m as the number of events during t. Is this right? I mean it should be right - he is professor in Harvard - but I don't get it.

Comment: At the decay example they deviate the poisson distribution by increasing the number of intervals and decreasing the length of the intervals. The starting point is not the poisson distribution, it is the conlcusion. At the other paragraph they apply the CLT.

Answer (score 1):

The answer on my question is in the same script:

Sometimes we add the values of the draws from a distribution instead of averaging them. In
this case, the mean $\bar{x}$ grows as  $N\bar{x}$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$ grows like $\sqrt{N}\sigma$.

Where N is somehow the time t we measure (for example the radioactive decay)

Answer (score 0):

If you have $N$ independent Poisson random variables, each with parameter $\lambda$, their sum is Poisson with parameter $N\lambda$.  So a Poisson random
variable with large parameter can be considered as a sum of independent Poisson random variables, and you can apply the Central Limit Theorem to that.